# JavaScript select specific child element that specific element after it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how to select a specific child element / child elements that have `<ul>` element after it in vanilla JavaScript.

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="para">Test1</div>
    <div class="para">Test2</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="para">Test 3</div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="para">Test 4</div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="para">Test 5</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to select all the `<div>`s that have a `<ul>` tag after them and give them `padding-bottom: 16px`.

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Is there a way to do this in CSS?

Comment: Do you mean Vanilla JS? As you've tagged both jQuery and React. Also, yes, you can do this strictly in CSS - some basic Googling would show you this.

Comment: What is the specific element after it? You mention you want to select Test 1, but for that the element after it is irrelevant.

Comment: @revilheart I updated the question. I would like to select all the <div> that have <ul> element after them.

Comment: @Eunicorn Still can't understand it. All the s that have tag after them? What?

Comment: @revilheart You see how the <ul> tag is placed after the <div>. I would like to select that specific element that has <ul> tag after it. So for the example that I provided. It would be <div> with "Test 2". Do you understand where I am going?

Comment: Well do you want to do it in JS or in CSS?

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
.para:first-child
```

or in JS

```
document.getElementsByClassName("para")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is practical, but I'm not aware of any CSS method for doing this. There are selectors for selecting elements with a certain element before them, but not after, as far as I know.

```js
let element, elements, i, n;
elements = document.getElementsByTagName(`div`); // get all div elements in the page
for (i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; i++) {
    element = elements[i];
    if (element.nextElementSibling && element.nextElementSibling.tagName === `UL`) {
        // check if the next element is a UL element
        element.style.paddingBottom = `16px`;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="para">Test1</div>
    <div class="para">Test2</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="para">Test 2</div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="para">Test 3</div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="para">Test 4</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @jhpratt No, it doesn't. If you replace `Test1` with `Test 2` it will add the padding to the second element.

Comment: @revilheart No, I am not looking for element containing specific text. I am looking to select all the <div> elements that have <ul> element after them. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Eunicorn Edited my answer with a possible solution.